How to ship & use custom python environment at all executor nodes in pyspark in a Jupyter notebook (running on dataproc)?
I am using pyspark in Jupyter notebook (running on dataproc) and have a custom python enviroment named m3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz which I want to ship to all the executor nodes and use this custom python library. I see that the custom enviroment (m3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz) has been shipped to all executors in their current home directory. However the python version and libraries version it is using is the default one.
Default python version & library details:
Python: 3.10.8
Pandas : '1.4.4'
numpy: '1.22.4'
sklearn: 1.1.3'
Customer python version & libraray details:
Python: 3.8.13
Pandas : '2.0.3'
numpy: '1.24.4'
sklearn: '1.3.2'
Following is my code in jupter notebook
import os
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

env_gs_path = "gs://<path>/notebooks/jupyter/ami-notebooks/m3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .appName("MyPySparkApp") \
                    .config("spark.yarn.queue", "adhoc_queue") \
                    .config('spark.submit.deployMode','client') \
                    .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Xlog:gc*") \
                    .config("spark.yarn.dist.archives",
                            env_gs_path) \
                    .config("spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON", "./m3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz/bin/python") \
                    .config("spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON", "./m3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz/bin/python") \
                    .config("spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH", "./m3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz/bin/python") \
                    .getOrCreate()


def check_python_version():
    import sys, os, pandas, numpy, sklearn
    return sys.version, pandas.__version__, sklearn.__version__, os.listdir("./")

# Parallelize a small dataset to distribute across executors
data = range(5)
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

# Use map transformation to execute the function on each executor
python_versions = rdd.map(lambda x: check_python_version()).collect()


# Print out Python versions
for i, version in enumerate(python_versions):
    print(f"Executor {i + 1} is using Python version: {version}")


The output is below:
Executor 1 is using Python version: ('3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:23:14) [GCC 10.4.0]', '1.4.4', '1.1.3', ['__spark_conf__', 'py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip', '.default_container_executor.sh.crc', 'launch_container.sh', '.default_container_executor_session.sh.crc', 'm3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz', '.launch_container.sh.crc', 'tmp', 'default_container_executor_session.sh', 'pyspark.zip', '.container_tokens.crc', 'container_tokens', 'default_container_executor.sh'])
Executor 2 is using Python version: ('3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:23:14) [GCC 10.4.0]', '1.4.4', '1.1.3', ['default_container_executor_session.sh', '.launch_container.sh.crc', 'm3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz', 'default_container_executor.sh', '.container_tokens.crc', '__spark_conf__', 'launch_container.sh', 'py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip', 'container_tokens', 'pyspark.zip', '.default_container_executor_session.sh.crc', 'tmp', '.default_container_executor.sh.crc'])
Executor 3 is using Python version: ('3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:23:14) [GCC 10.4.0]', '1.4.4', '1.1.3', ['__spark_conf__', 'py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip', '.default_container_executor.sh.crc', 'launch_container.sh', '.default_container_executor_session.sh.crc', 'm3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz', '.launch_container.sh.crc', 'tmp', 'default_container_executor_session.sh', 'pyspark.zip', '.container_tokens.crc', 'container_tokens', 'default_container_executor.sh'])
Executor 4 is using Python version: ('3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:23:14) [GCC 10.4.0]', '1.4.4', '1.1.3', ['default_container_executor_session.sh', '.launch_container.sh.crc', 'm3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz', 'default_container_executor.sh', '.container_tokens.crc', '__spark_conf__', 'launch_container.sh', 'py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip', 'container_tokens', 'pyspark.zip', '.default_container_executor_session.sh.crc', 'tmp', '.default_container_executor.sh.crc'])
Executor 5 is using Python version: ('3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:23:14) [GCC 10.4.0]', '1.4.4', '1.1.3', ['__spark_conf__', 'py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip', '.default_container_executor.sh.crc', 'launch_container.sh', '.default_container_executor_session.sh.crc', 'm3.Linux_debian_11.py38.simple-env.tar.gz', '.launch_container.sh.crc', 'tmp', 'default_container_executor_session.sh', 'pyspark.zip', '.container_tokens.crc', 'container_tokens', 'default_container_executor.sh'])


I see that the custom enviroment is present in the working directory of nodes but the libaries version imported & used were still the default ones not the custom libary. What am I missing?
I tried setting various configuration parameters like executor PYSPARK_PYTHON environment etc as mentioned above however wasn't succesfull.
